# How to use "git config" command to configure sections with name?

Tags: git, git-config

How could I use "git config" command to implement the configuration like this:

```
[diff "odf"]
  textconv=odt2txt
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
git config diff.odf.textconv odt2txt
```

This will result in:

```
[diff "odf"]
        textconv = odt2txt
```

Comment: Do you know why this isn't working for `git config global.user.name "My Name"`?

Comment: There is no configuration variable named `global.user.name`.  You want `git config --global user.name`